# How to unit test with Moq location/process

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, moq

So I am pretty new to testing, I never really done much, so my I may lack some fundamentals.

**Question 1:**
I am using ASP MVC4 and want to use Moq with my unit test case. After reading there are a lot of example, I see that I am suppose to have an interface. Where exactly should this go? In the controller folder, the test project?

**Question 2** 
If I am testing a method in my controller and it has multiple calls to the db how would I Moq that

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 var model = new myModel();
 var pList = new List<myModel.pType>();
 var sList = new List<myModel.sType>();
 var results = Class1.FetchPData(); // how would I mock this
 var result1 = Class1.FetchSData();  // how would I mock this

 for (int i = 0; i < results.Count(); i++)
 {
  ... do stuff
 }


 for (int j = 0; j < result1.Count(); j++)
 {
   ..do stuff
 }

    return View("Index", model);
 }
```

Will I have to create another method where it contains the same logic, but I will have to pass in "Mock Object" as a param to the method, and have that as an implementable method in my interface? Or re-implement my method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After reading there are a lot of example, I see that I am suppose to
>   have an interface. Where exactly should this go? In the controller
>   folder, the test project?

There is no rule where to keep interfaces, but usually you keep them closely to code which uses them. Usually I have domain classes and services in separate assembly with repository interfaces defined there. Then I reference this assembly by Data Access assembly which have implementations of repository interfaces. And last step - I reference both assemblies from web application.

> If I am testing a method in my controller and it has multiple calls to
>   the db how would I Moq that

Remember, good unit tests should be Fast, Isolated, Repeatable, Self-Verifying, and Timely ([FIRST](http://pragprog.com/magazines/2012-01/unit-tests-are-first)). Having database calls in controller does not allow you to run tests fast (database calls are very slow comparing to in-memory code), to test controller in isolation and make tests always repeatable. Also your controller simply does to many things (i.e. violates SRP principle) - it gets user input, makes database queries and prepares model for view.

So, in order to separate responsibilities and make your controller testable, you should
extract data-access related code to separate class (usually such classes called *repositories*). And create abstraction which will specify API between controller and repository:

```
public interface IYourRepository
{
     IEnumerable<pType> FetchPData();
     IEnumerable<sType> FetchSData();
}
```

Then make your controller depend on this abstraction (inverse dependency), and inject repository to controller (you can use Ninject, Unity or other dependency injection framework):

```
IYourRepository _repository;

public YourController(IYourRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new myModel();

    foreach (var p in _repository.FetchPData())
        // do stuff

    foreach (var s in _repository.FetchSData())
        // do stuff


    return View("Index", model);
}
```

That will allow you to mock repository easily and provide mocked object to controller:

```
var repositoryMock = new Mock<IYourRepository>();
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.FetchPData()).Returns(pList);
repositoryMock.Setup(r => r.FetchSData()).Returns(sList);

var controller = new YourController(repositoryMock.Object);
var result = controller.Index();

// Assertions
```

Comment: OK I understand know. So in the future I should write my method in a way that can also be easily mocked

Comment: I should mention that `FetchPData` and `FetchSData` are actaully static method called from another class.

Comment: @JackThor even after you edited question, answer is same - make them non-static and inject another class instance to controller

Comment: Awesome, so I assume things like this are learned through experience :)